# Enabling Airplay in iOS5 application

Tags: iphone, ios5, airplay

I have created a simple application to read video files and it is opened using quicklook framwork. Now i want to integrate airplay support for users to view in apple TV.

So do i have to do something for it in quick look or it is built in?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually open the video files and launch a player?

Comment: Yes i open video in quicklook